# why does bazel copy resources from subdirectories to the top level of a jar

Tags: java, resources, bazel, filegroup

So the BUILD structure are like below:

java:

```
/src/java/com/abc/code/Code.java
```

resources:

```
/src/resources/com/abc/code/application.properties
```

BUILD filegroups

```
filegroup(
    name = "properties",
    srcs = glob(["application.properties"])
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

BUILD of app
use filegroups as resources/classpath_resources

```
java_binary(
    name = "app",
    classpath_resources = [
        "//src/resources/com/abc/code:properties",
    ],
    # resources = [
    #     "//src/resources/com/abc/code:properties",
    # ],
    main_class = "com.abc.code.Code",
    runtime_deps = [
        ":app_bin",
    ],
)
```

get `null` back for `Code.class.getResourceAsStream("application.properties");`

and after checking the generated jar, found that application.properties sits in the top `/`

```
jar tf poc_delivery_system_app.jar
```

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
application.properties
```

then update the code to  `Code.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");` which works,

The question is why `application.properties` is in the top level instead of something like `/com/abc/code/application.properties`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So the title of the question should be something like "why does bazel copy resources from subdirectories to the top level of a jar"?

Comment: The documentation for `classpath_resources` says "A list of resources that must be located at the root of the java tree" (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary.classpath_resources). Are you sure you saw the same behavior using the `resources` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The resources have the following resource(s)

```
srcs = glob(["application.properties"])
```

So, indeed they are at the source.

If you want them in a subdirectory, place the BUILD file at `$WORKSPACE/src/resources/BUILD` with

```
filegroup(
  name = "resources",
  srcs = glob(["**/*.properties"]),
)
```

and the java lib will then

```
  resources = [
     "//src/resources",
  ],
```